# Select multiple elements in xslt

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT. I have one issue and one question.
The issue:
I have a xml similar to:

```
<data>
  <element>
     <Title>Title1</Title>
     <Author>Author1</Author>
  </element>
  <element>
     <Title>Title2</Title>
     <Author>Author2</Author>
  </element>
  <element>
     <Title>Title3</Title>
     <Author>Author3</Author>
  </element>
  <element>
     <Title>Title4</Title>
     <Author>Author4</Author>
  </element>
  (...)
</data>
```

I want to get a structure similar to:

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding:2px 0px 5px 0px;">
           Title1 Author1
           Title2 Author2
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding:2px 0px 5px 0px;">
           Title3 Author3
           Title4 Author4
        </td>
      </tr>
     (...)
</table>
```

Please observe that authors 1,2 are grouped together, similarly 3 and 4. They are grouped based on position (instead of `Author1` I will have a name, of course, so I cannot extract the number from inside the xml). 
Position 1 with Position 2
Position 3 with Position 4
...

I tried something like this in my xslt:

```
<xsl:for-each select="element">
      <xsl:if test="(position() mod 2 = 0)">
        <tr>    <------ THIS APPEARS AS NOT CLOSED
          <td style="padding:2px 0px 5px 0px;">    <------ THIS APPEARS AS NOT CLOSED
            <xsl:call-template name="content"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="(position() mod 2 = 1)">
        <xsl:call-template name="content"/>
        </td> <------ THIS WOULD BE THE CLOSED TD
        </tr> <------ THIS WOULD BE THE CLOSED TR
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

`<xsl:call-template name="content"/>` just fetches the needed information for me, nothing fancy, just `xsl:value-of select`.

Question:

1. How do I generate the open and closed `<td>` and `<tr>`? The xslt above does compile, since it looks like the `td` and `tr` might remain unclosed and this seems to be illegal.
2. I heard that `for-each` in xslt is a bad pattern. Is it true and if yes, what would it be recommended?

I am using XslCompiledTransform in C#, so xslt 2 should work.

Comment: Your explanation contradicts itself. _"Please observe that authors 1,2 are grouped, similarly 3 and 4. I will have odd and even authors grouped"_  "Odd and even authors grouped" would be [1,3] and [2,4].  Which is it? What if there's more than 4?

Comment: A XSLT document must be a well-formed XML document. You need to nest the tags properly.

Comment: You should also tell us which XSLT engine you're using and whether or not you can use XSLT2.

Comment: How is `Title 1` related to `Author 3` in your source document? Are you discarding `Title 3` and `Title 4`? What are the rules for the grouping?

Comment: 1 and 2 are grouped together, just like in the example. Similarly 3, 4 are grouped and the list will continue with 5,6 then 7,8 ,etc. I edited the question and now it should be accurate. I am using xslcompiledtransform, so xslt2 should work I guess.

Comment: You mean in pairs, based on their position? And what about the text inside the `td`. Is the extra whitespace irrelevant?

Comment: yes, in pairs based on position. I don't see the extra space you are talking about, but it is irrelevant. As you can see, I am trying to get some sort of html out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSLT should get you started. I added the spaces, but if they are irrelevant you can simply remove the `<xsl:text>` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="element[(position()+1) mod 2 = 0]"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:2px 0px 5px 0px;">
                <xsl:text>&#xa;         </xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;         </xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::element[1]/*"/>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;      </xsl:text>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Title">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Author">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You don't need any for-each blocks or complex nesting, since each template is processed recursively for each node, so the same template is processed multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/data">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="element[position() mod 2 = 1]">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Author"/>
                    <br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::element[1]/Title"/>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::element[1]/Author"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```